# Mysql truncating difficult characters

Tags: c++, mysql, boost, utf-8, character-encoding

Having trouble with a character getting either omitted or changing to something weird, somewhere between loading some html from a site, and saving it into a database. Here's the flow:

Loading site with libcurl, this is the content of the write function:

```
static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}
```

The site has utf8 set as the encoding type in the html.

The string remains as an std::string, which then gets passed onto Mysql cppconn to be entered into a database table.

The collation of the table is set to utf8_unicode_ci, as is the field in question.

But when I view the contents of the table in Adminer, the text in the field has been truncated, and only shows the first half of the text, just regular characters before the difficult character (é).

---

One thing I've noticed is that in the cout outputs throughout the program the é is never shown correctly, instead shows the question mark in the diamond symbol. The terminal is set to Current Locale: UTF-8.

This made me think maybe what I'm getting from libcurl isn't actually utf-8, so I used the boost library to try changing it to utf-8 using:

```
std::locale loc("");
std::locale conv_loc = boost::locale::util::create_info(loc, loc.name());
std::string output = boost::locale::conv::to_utf<char>(codepage_str, conv_loc);
```

I tried putting this just before the return in the write function i pasted above, the effect was that it just cut the offending character out of the text though.

What am I overlooking here?

---

Have now have an output of what the problematic name and it's utf8 values, how does help me though?

```
Cuauht�moc Ruelas - 0x43 0x75 0x61 0x75 0x68 0x74 0xffffffe9 0x6d 0x6f 0x63 0x20 0x52 0x75 0x65 0x6c 0x61 0x73
```

Comment: What is the actual (utf-8) value in the string where the character is located?  Does it jibe with the character codepoint as defined by UTF-8?  That's the first thing you should be inspecting -- don't use cout (unless you are outputting the integer value of the character).  You should be inspecting each string, byte by byte, to ensure the string is correct, starting from the source string (follow it through and note where the disconnect occurs).

Comment: How do I check what the actual utf-8 value is in the string where the character is located?

Comment: `for (auto ch : string_value) std::cout << std;:hex << std::setw(2) << std::showbase << static_cast<int>(ch) << " ";`, e.g.

Comment: @GemmaB89 Basically, you're using the wrong tools to diagnose the issue.  You should be dumping (as the previous comment suggested) the character value, one-by-one.  If not that, in your debugger, inspect the string not as a "std::string", but get a pointer to the actual buffer and look at the memory.   The issue of using "high-level" routines such as `cout << std::string` is that you may totally miss any characters that your console (or your debugger) may be masking.

Comment: That makes sense, sorry quite new to this, this is the output:

Cuauht�moc Ruelas - 0x43 0x75 0x61 0x75 0x68 0x74 0xffffffe9 0x6d 0x6f 0x63 0x20 0x52 0x75 0x65 0x6c 0x61 0x73

Comment: Well, look at this table:  http://www.utf8-chartable.de/  You will see that the outlier in your string is `0xffffffe9`.  Looks like the Unicode code point, not UTF-8.

Comment: So what would I need to do, convert the string from unicode to utf8?

Comment: @GemmaB89 I don't know what to tell you.  What I did show you is how to display the actual character.  You need to go through what you're doing, from beginning to end, and figure out the source of the issue, who/what is responsible for making those characters that way, or if you need to do something (that I wouldn't know about) to work so that you start out with a good string.

Comment: OK, thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that's just the sign extension due to signed char (that's implementation defined). So, to "fix" it it would be `static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch))`. I didn't think that was necessary, it would be kinda obvious... It's not an outlier. It's the expected UTF8 multibyte leader

Comment: `e9` is hex for the _latin1_ encoding of `é`.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually solved the problem myself:

The site I was loading with libcurl said it was utf8 in the html character encoding meta tag, but the error seemed to be there as soon as libcurl had the response string.

I decided to check what character encoding the html file on the site was actually in, and did this using the Chardet python module.

Running this python code:

```
import urllib
urlread = lambda url: urllib.urlopen(url).read()
import chardet
print chardet.detect(urlread("http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/little_boy_2015/reviews/"))
```

Gave me: {'confidence': 0.8129867552228945, 'encoding': 'ISO-8859-2'}

Character encoding detection isn't perfect, hence the confidence not being 1, but I then used Boost locale in c++ to convert the string from ISO-8859-2 to UTF8 straight after receiving it, and now the correct character shows up everywhere perfectly :)